# Center of shortest connection between two lines in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have two **skew** lines:

$g_l: \overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{a}+r\overrightarrow{u}$

$g_r: \overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{b}+s\overrightarrow{v}$

How can I calculate the center point of the shortest connection of these lines $g_l$ and $g_r$?

Comment: The shortest distance between 2 skew lines can be done as follow: Create a plane containing the two directional vectors of the lines. One of the lines lies entirely in the plane. The problem is now reduced to calculating distance between a line and the plane, which can be done through a formula, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html

Comment: Which letters correspond to vectors and which to scalars? Do you know what scalar product is?

Comment: @DavidQuinn: I've added arrows above the corresponding letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is as follows.

Write $$\overrightarrow{w}=\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}+r\overrightarrow{u}-s\overrightarrow{v}$$

This is the vector joining two points, one on each of the lines.

Form and solve a simultaneous equation for $r$ and $s$ by setting $$\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{u}=0$$ and $$\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{v}=0$$

This ensures that the line joining is perpendicular to both given lines.

Then the position vector of the centre of the shortest line, using the values of $r$ and $s$ obtained, is $$\frac 12(\overrightarrow{a}+\overrightarrow{b}+r\overrightarrow{u}+s\overrightarrow{v})$$